# MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method check on channel plugins.flutter.io/connectivity)

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, connectivity

I'm having the following error when I'm running my flutter application on WEB, but it works fine on Android.

```
Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method check on channel plugins.flutter.io/connectivity)
    at Object.createErrorWithStack (http://localhost:64900/dart_sdk.js:5348:12)
    at Object._rethrow (http://localhost:64900/dart_sdk.js:39350:16)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:64900/dart_sdk.js:39344:13)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:64900/dart_sdk.js:39176:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:64900/dart_sdk.js:39182:13)
    at http://localhost:64900/dart_sdk.js:34689:9
```

I debug the code and the problem is on this method:

```
@override
  Future<ConnectivityResult> checkConnectivity() async {
    final String checkResult =
        await methodChannel.invokeMethod<String>('check') ?? '';
    return parseConnectivityResult(checkResult);
  }
```

I'm using Connectivity 3.0.3 and Flutter 2.0 stable channel
I also searched the web and stackoverflow but I couldn't find and answer to my specific case.
I also try flutter clean and rebuild with no results.

Comment: I informed wrong connectivity version. The correct version is 3.0.2

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [connectivity_for_web](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_for_web) as well.

Hope this solves your issue!